# Use different dataframe inside PySpark UDF

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I got a dataframe (`df1`), where I have listed some time frames:

```
| start | end | event name |
|-------|-----|------------|
| 1     | 3   | name_1     |
| 3     | 5   | name_2     |
| 2     | 6   | name_3     |
```

In these time frames, I would like to extract some data from another dataframe (`df2`). For example, I want to extend `df1` with the average measurementn from `df2` inside the specified time range.

```
| timestamp | measurement |
|-----------|-------------|
| 1         | 5           |
| 2         | 7           |
| 3         | 5           |
| 4         | 9           |
| 5         | 2           |
| 6         | 7           |
| 7         | 8           |
```

I was thinking about an UDF function which filters `df2` by timestamp and evaluates the average. But in a UDF I can not reference two dataframes:

```
def get_avg(start, end):
  return df2.filter(df2.timestamp > start & df2.timestamp < end).agg({"average": "avg"})

udf_1 = f.udf(get_avg)

df1.select(udf_1('start', 'end').show()
```

This will throw an error `TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object`.

How would I solve this issue efficiently?

Comment: Have you considered using Pandas UDFs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case there is no need to use UDFs, you can simply use `join` over a range interval determined by the timestamps

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1.join(df2, on=[(df2.timestamp > df1.start) & (df2.timestamp < df1.end)]) \
  .groupby('start', 'end', 'event_name') \
  .agg(F.mean('measurement').alias('avg')) \
  .show()

+-----+---+----------+-----------------+
|start|end|event_name|              avg|
+-----+---+----------+-----------------+
|    1|  3|    name_1|              7.0|
|    3|  5|    name_2|              9.0|
|    2|  6|    name_3|5.333333333333333|
+-----+---+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks a lot. That looks much easier and also brings a lot of performance improvements compared to my other solutions that I tried.